# How to get row and column count from excel file using Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using selenium Ide and I want number of rows and columns available within the excel file. 
[Excel file Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyMP3.png)

For example, in above the excel has 3 columns and 6  rows. So, using selenium IDE how can I find these numbers?

Comment: Can you please explain your scenario. Why you want to read from Excel?

Comment: Are you wanting to use this data to support a test? Or are you saying you just want to use selenium to test the excel document itself? i.e. you run the test, and the output is 'This document has x rows and y columns?' Because Selenium IDE can only 'test' within the firefox browser, using plugins you can link to an external document to provide inputs into your tests, but to my knowledge that's the extent of it's ability to interact with external files

Comment: Hey Sagar007, currently I want to automate the process where I have data of college students in excel format and I need to first find out how many rows and columns are available in the spreadsheet and then I can map the row and column number to fetch data within each cell and add it in my DB through a web form.

Comment: As per selenium IDE understanding , It is only support xml file with selblock plugin. I suggest you to user Selenium Webdriver (Write script) for your solution. Advantage is you can identify rows and columns with data with simple line of codes.